# Google Sheets: Creating a practice test from a bank of questions and answers

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have a spreadsheet where one sheet has a list of 100 questions in column 1 along with the answers in column 2. In another sheet I want to display 20 random questions from the list of 100 along with the answers to the questions at the bottom of those rows.

On my main sheet I have this "practice test"

[image]

On a second sheet titled "Data" I have a bank of questions and answers in column 1 and 2...

[image]

I'd like the practice test to auto generate a new set of 5 random questions and show their correlating answers in the answer key.

The formula I found to populate the list of questions is this put into Practicetest!B1 ...
`=ARRAY_CONSTRAIN( SORT( FILTER(Data!A2:A, Data!A2:A<>""), RANDARRAY( COUNTA(Data!A2:A), 1), TRUE), 50, 1)`

It works to give me a random list of 5 questions every minute as long as I have the recalculation setting turned to every minute.

However what I cannot figure out is how to get the associated answer for the question into the answer key at the bottom.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `ARRAY_CONSTRAIN-SORT`, You can use [`SORTN`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/7354624?hl=en) to get the 5 random questions:

```cpp
=SORTN(TOCOL(Data!A:A,1),5,,RANDARRAY(COUNTA(Data!A:A)),)
```

*(Note that I also replaced `FILTER` with [`TOCOL`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/13187258?hl=en) to remove blanks)*

And [`VLOOKUP`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093318?hl=en) to get the corresponding answers:

```cpp
=ARRAYFORMULA(VLOOKUP(B1:B5,Data!A:B,2,))
```